# How to get the xml-stylesheet value from a xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, header, stylesheet

I have an XML containing below header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chb/sample_ccdas/master/CDA.xsl"?>
```

How could I get the value of `href` using java.
I have tried using `XPath and XMLStreamReader` but couldn't find a way to get it.

It is giving null value if I use the XPath as below:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')");
String url = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Where `xpath is XPath object and doc is Document object`

Answer (score 0):

Try XPath `/processing-instruction(xml-stylesheet)`

See also [How can i modify xml-stylesheet attribute value in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715976/how-can-i-modify-xml-stylesheet-attribute-value-in-java)

Comment: It is returning null for me. Modified the question to reflect the code I am using

Comment: did you try with something like `XPathConstants.NODE` ? Think it is a a node/element not a `String`

Comment: Tried like this, but it is still returning null.                                                Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

Comment: Plain `expr.evaluate(doc);` returns `type="text/xsl" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chb/sample_ccdas/master/CDA.xsl"` for me but also with `NODE` & `NODESET` it is not `null`. Can you attach your document ? Maybe it has something wrong?